# Problem with biblatex-chem bundle when used with option pageranges=false

Tags: biblatex

I'm using Joseph Wright's excellent `biblatex-chem` bundle for `biblatex` emulating the styles of certain chemistry journals. In particular I'm using

```
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,pageranges=false]{biblatex}
```

with `biblatex` version 1.5a. The problem is that this produces output where the page number of an article is preceded by "p.", i.e.

J. P. Perdew, K. Burke, M. Ernzerhof, *Phys. Rev. Lett.* **1996**, *77*, p. 3865.

But this behaviour does not match the journal's (*Angewandte Chemie*) standards as pages of articles should not include a prefix like "p." (and also my professor wants me to get rid of it).
While I searched in the appropriate style file of `biblatex-chem` (`chem-angew.bbx`) to see which command is connected to the package option `pageranges=false` I found out that it is `\mkpagefirst`. The related line in `chem-angew.bbx` is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{%
\ifbool{bbx:pageranges}{#1}{\mkpagefirst{#1}}%
}
```

Next I tried to look up the original definition of this command in `biblatex.sty` in order to use it as a template for a redefinition via `renewcommand` that suits my needs. 
But as `\mkpagefirst` is defined via a cascade of commands I can't figure out how to do it. So any help would be very much appreciated. 
(I'm not sure whether this can be regarded as a bug in the `biblatex-chem` bundle which I should report to Joseph Wright since he might have intended it to work that way.)

Comment: I'm aware of the issue with `biblatex` 1.6, but need to sort out some issues with the way I originally structured the code. The BitBucket site (https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/biblatex-chem) should get updated as I work on this: I probably need a week to address the 'big issues'.

Comment: Your work is very much appreciated as I use your package for every document I have to produce in the course of my studies. Saved me a lot of work.

Comment: I've just submitted a new version of `biblatex-chem` to CTAN. This should fix both your issue and the wider problem with `biblatex` v1.6. Give it a day or so to make its way around the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I have updated my `biblatex` to version 1.6 I see that the newly introduced command `\mkfirstpage` fixes the behaviour of `biblatex-chem`'s package option `pageranges=false` if one substitutes `\mkpagefirst` to `\mkfirstpage` in the `chem-angew.bbx` file. But as pointed out in the comments to Marco's answer the current version (1.0e) of `biblatex-chem` is not compatible with `biblatex` 1.6. Until an official update to the bundle is released I fixed this incompatibility by applying the following changes to the `chem-angew.bbx` file: 
I removed the lines

```
\renewcommand*{\thebibitem}{\item}
\renewcommand*{\thelositem}{\item}
```

Furthermore I changed

```
\renewenvironment*{thebibliography}
 {\list
    {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
```

to

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{prefixnumber}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

and

```
\renewenvironment*{theshorthands}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}}
  {\endlist}
```

to

```
\defbibenvironment{shorthands}
  {\list
     {\printfield[shorthandwidth]{shorthand}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\shorthandwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

This solved my problem so far. I guess similar changes to the respective style files might be necessary to use the other styles contained in the `biblatex-chem` bundle.

Answer (score 2):

By using `biblatex` 1.6 the bundle `biblatex-chem` produces some errors. I build a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\providecommand*\thebibitem{}
\providecommand*\thelositem{}
\providecommand*\theshorthands{}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,pageranges=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{entry1,
author="J. P. Perdew and K. Burke and M. Ernzerhof",
journaltitle="Phys. Rev. Lett.",
volume="77",
year="1996",
pages="3865"
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\cite{entry1}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And I get no "p. 3865".

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem. When I compile your minimal example I get "S. 3865", i.e. the german analog of "p. 3865", which I don't want as output as well. Have you used `biblatex` v. 1.6 for this example or was it only a side note that this version produces errors with `biblatex-chem`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had to uncomment the `\providecommand`s before I could compile your minimal example because for some reasons I get error messages when they are included.

Comment: I am using version 1.6. I need the `providecommand`. I think Jospeh Wright will update his `biblatex-chem` to be compatible with biblatex version 1.6.

Comment: I read in the `biblatex` documentation that the `\mkpagefirst` command is removed in version 1.6. Maybe the errors you get are due to this. But my problem remains that I need a proper redefinition of `\mkpagefirst` in order to use `biblatex-chem`.

Comment: You are right. With the version 1.6 Phillip Lehmann added the new command `mkfirstpage` and other nice gimmicks to handle pages.